# If $\{f>a\}$ is measurable $\forall a \in \mathbb{Q}$ show that $f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function if $E$ is measurable and $\{f>a\}$ is measurable $\forall a \in \mathbb{Q}$ show that $f$ is measurable

---

Let $\{f>a\}\in \mathcal{M} , \forall a \in \mathbb{Q}$

let $b \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

I can find a rational decreeing sequence $q_n, \: n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $q_n\to b$

$\{f\geq b\}=\cap _{n=1}^{\infty}\{f\geq q_n\}$ by taking limits, is it correct that $\{f\geq b\}\in \mathcal{M}$ ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh why $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ ? You meant $E$ ?

Comment: @lupusnox Your reasoning is correct, what doubts do you have???

Comment: @copper.hat I guess this is correct too since we are using the properties of the sigma algebra which they hold for the intersections